# WP can't create new directory

Tags: themes, permissions

**Edit2**: I'm renaming the question from "WP didn't add theme automatically" to "WP can't create new directory" because I found out that the problem is a little bit more complex. The same error is going on on any operation I do that involves writing data to `/var/www/html/wordpress`. I already tried what has been suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162866/correct-permissions-for-var-www-and-wordpress), tried also to `gpasswd -a www-data sudo` and nothing... I have no idea now what to do. **/Edit2**

I was just following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7olvEeBM2I&list=PLpcSpRrAaOaqMA4RdhSnnNcaqOVpX7qi5&index=3) tutorial, I did exactly like he did from 02:30 to 03:30: added a folder in `/wp-content/themes/mytheme`, inside mytheme added a style.css and index.php. When I went to dashboard it wasn't added automatically so I tried to upload the theme.zip manually. Now I'm getting the error message "Could not create directory". I already set `chmod -R 777` to wordpress folder but still having this

**Edit:**

Output of `ls -la /var/www/html/wordpress`:

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 fabio www-data 20 Jan  4 16:45 /var/www/html/wordpress -> /usr/share/wordpress

Output of `ls -ld /usr/share/wordpress`:

> drwxrwxrwx 5 www-data root 4096 Jan  8 15:46 /usr/share/wordpress

In my theme folder I got only `index.php` and `style.css`, that's how they are atm:

`index.php`:

```
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
```

`style.css`:

```
/*
Theme Name: ThemeTutorial
Theme URI: http://github.com/FabioNevesRezende
Author: fabiotk
Author URI: http://github.com/FabioNevesRezende
Description: Descrição do tema
Version: 1.0
Tags: black, brown, orange, tan, white, yellow, light, one-column, two-columns, right-sidebar, flexible-width, custom-header, custom-menu, editor-style, featured-images, microformats, post-formats, rtl-language-support, sticky-post, translation-ready
Text Domain: twentythirteen

Este tema foi criado por Fábio Neves Rezende
*/
```

I put those github links just because I got no other link to put, I think this won't make any error, right?

Answer (score 0):

Does your style.css file have something like this at the top, customized to your theme?

```
/*
Theme Name: ! Startups in Boston
Theme URI: http://bostonstartupsguide.com/
Author: Jay Neely
Author URI: http://socialstrategist.com
Description: Theme for BostonStartupsGuide.com. Initially built using Whiteboard Framework (http://whiteboardframework.com), redesigned using HTML 5 Boilerplate and inspired by 960.gs.
Version: 1.0
 */
```